# Is there a way to hide the keyboard without losing the focus of the EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyboard, focus

When you click the back button, the keyboard hides itself but the focus on the edittext remains. How can I reproduce this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to hide the keyboard:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
);
```

Or this one :

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

If the EditText loses the focus, simple write a simple command

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: the keyboard wont close even if I remove the requestFocus() part.

Comment: requestFocus() is to bring focus on the View. But use the above code above that to hide keyboard.

Comment: Yes indeed but the above code (the close keyboard part) is not working either.

Comment: It works! My problem was that i set the visiblity to GONE when closing the keyboard, hence automatically removing the focus. Our designer suggested to leave the visiiblity and it works lol :D